# How to reopen map fragment or popup from backstack

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am pretty confused right now with maps

What i am doing is that i opened a fragment(lets take it as A) that includes two other fragments. i.e my Map fragment(Fragment B) and other fragment for list view(Fragment c).

Fragment A is opened every time when a function is called and Fragment A calls Fragment B and C.

What i get is an exception in inflating map.

To avoid this i want to pop the map fragment from back stack if it is already opened.

This is what i am doing

This is done in Fragment A

```
private void setUpView() {
    SearchResultList returnedList = new SearchResultList();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.search_result_List, returnedList,
            "Search Result List Fragment");

    SearchLocationFragment returnedMap = new SearchLocationFragment();
    Fragment frag = fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag("Search Result Map Fragment");
    if (frag == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.search_result_Map, returnedMap,
                "Search Result Map Fragment").commit();
    } else {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack("Search Result Map Fragment",
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    if (userDataFrag.searchResult.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new AllPostAdapter((BaseActivity) getActivity(),
                userDataFrag.searchResult, false);
        searchSideLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

This is Layout For fragment A

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_result_List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_result_Map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have a button in My Fragment a that cause toggle between Fragment B and C

Kindly Help me with this.

Thanx in advance